# Does a mvc6 service provides project.json data?

Tags: service, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, project.json

I am using asp.net 5 with mvc6, and I extended the project.json with several stuffs.

I am currently reading the project.json by parsing it myself. But I was wondering whether a service or a context exists within mvc6 already providing parsed data of project.json file.

Comment: Parsing of `project.json` and **extension** of it with custom information are two different things. It's not recommended to extend `project.json`, which schema is well-known. It's better to use `appsettings.json` (or any other .json file) for the application configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your concern and your anwser Oleg, really appreciating. I take into account your remark.
However, from a **conception** point of view, I have my reasons to consider that what I add in project.json is relevant.
That's why I am very interested in your **technical** point of view. Could you just precise why or by who project.json extension is not recommended?
My technical point of view is actually json files are by design extensibles (quite similar examples are package.json, bower.json ...)

Comment: You are welcome! From the technical point of view you can import the information using `var project = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("project.json").Build();` and then the usage of `var mvcVersion = project["dependencies:Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc"];` to get the string like `"6.0.0-rc1-final"`. Is it want you need? [The part of documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html) describes more advances scenarios, but `appsettings.json` is the the default configuration file used for application specific settings.

Comment: `project.json` will be used *for another purpose*. For example Visual Studio monitors the changes in `project.json`. If you changes `"dependencies"` section then it start Restore Packages immediately. Why you should change the file existing for another purpose? I think that one can extend `project.json` from the *technical* point of view, but I would not recommend you to do this from design point of view and for reducing the side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no service, you have to parse it yourself

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess this definitly anwsers my question

Answer (score 0):

Why are you parsing manually project.json? Don't do that. If you wan't to have custom configuration settings then create new file or use one of existing ones (for example appsettings.json). Then in Startup.cs simply add that file and it will be available in the Configuration object:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

    ...

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concern.
However, I am afraid this do not really answers my question. I have actually my reasons to think that from a **conception** point of view, extending project.json is relevant.
But if there is any issue in extending project.jon - like I said in oleg's answer -, I am very interested in getting your **technical** point of view. Could you just precise why extending project.json is a bad thing or what issue I am exposed to?

Comment: I like to stick what does ASP.NET team propose. Create new project from a template, you will have your project.json and appsettings.json. Why? In my opinion to put there you application options. For me project.json is for more global application configuration like definition of project’s server side dependencies.

Comment: Thanks dawidr, I totally agree with your way of thinking. In particular when you said:
"project.json is for more global application configuration like definition of project’s server side dependencies". This is actually the way I extended project.json :-)